# Partitioning based on distribution

Tags: ds.algorithms, approximation-algorithms, packing, greedy-algorithms, partition-problem

Having a set of numbers $S={s_i}$, I want to assign them to bins, $b_i$, such that the sum of items on bins follow a specific distribution.

For two bins and uniform distribution, this problem is similar to the partition problem. I know there is a simple greedy algorithm for that but I could not generalize it for my problem.

Comment: There's no "simple greedy algorithm" for the partition problem if you want to solve it exactly in polynomial time

Comment: I saw this algorithm on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#The_greedy_algorithm

Comment: Yes. that's a heuristic though. I assume you want an algorithm with precise guarantees ?